# Get selected labels from SelectManyListBox

Tags: java, jsf

I want to get value *and* label of the selected items of a `h:selectManyListbox`.

I've this:

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="myList" size="10" value="#{search.selectedItems}">
    <f:selectItems id="myListID" value="#{search.itemsList}">
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

The problem is that when I submit the form I get only the a `List<String>` value and I need both: values and labels selected.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. HTML won't send the option label to the server side. Besides, you normally **already** know the label associated with the value in the server side. Just have some mapping of label-value pairs (e.g. `Map<String, String>`) so that you can obtain the associated label by the selected value (even more, you can reuse the map in `<f:selectItems>`).

That said, the need to know the label is a design smell. Shouldn't this information go in the value in first place (as well)?

Comment: yeah that would be an option, but i've names of clients with extrange characters like ', ", /, \, etc... and have repeated names to, so i can't use this like a value. thanks for the answer i'll try the map<String, String> thing